# Migration Assistant doesnt recognize external time machine disk

Tags: backup, time-machine, migration

I am trying to migrate my information (including applications) from my old MacBook (OSX 10.8.5) to my new MBP (El Capitan) using a recent Time Machine backup, but Migration Assistant is not able to recognize as a source the external disk connected to the USB port. Instead it seems to be stuck on "searching".

How can I manage to "connect" the disk to Migration Assistant?

Comment: Is the Time Machine disk you're trying to use actually mounted? That is. can you see it in Finder?